# Get position of sort by in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Let's say I have 10  books in a database. When I sort by the Name, I want the first book to have a 'rank' of 1. And so on and so forth, within the query.

I cannot use the auto incremented id.

[1] A

[2] B

[3] C

Etc.

My scenario is coins and using Yii2.

```
    $coins = Coins::find()
        ->select(['id', 'name', 'icon', 'volume_24_hours', 'market_cap', 'price', 'change_24_hours', 'circulating_supply', 'abbreviation'])
        ->where(['is_fiat' => false])
        ->orWhere(['is_fiat' => null])
        ->orderBy(['volume_24_hours' => 'DESC']);
```

Comment: remeber that if you manage the result with a dataProvider and grid view you  you can use the related special  column for numbering a sequence

Comment: Can you clarify? I am using a GridView and ADP for this, but what is a special column? You mean customize the columns array on the gridview to display my custom selected rownumber?

Comment: If i undertsand correcly your special column is a number sequence .. an equivalent sequnce can be produced  using  the 'yii\grid\SerialColumn' class ..in gridview column

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, Postgre and MSSQL you can use some form of **row_number** function. In MySql you can [emulate it](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/) with the help of variables.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works for you.. (:

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY BookName ASC)  AS RowNo,
          BookName
FROM   TableName
```